# How to solve for amplitude w.r.t time for a dad pushing his daughter on the swing with periodic force impulses?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A Dad is pushing his daughter on a swing. The homogeneous push lasts for α = 10% of the period and is centered around the phase φ = 0. The Fourier series expansion for this is,
$$
f(t)=\alpha+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n\pi}\,sin(n\pi\alpha)\,cos(2\pi nt)
$$ 
where α is the fraction of the period that the push is applied. The swing can be treated as a harmonic oscillator with friction. Let the period of the corresponding undamped oscillator be the same as the period the Dad is pushing with.

How do I analytically solve for the amplitude as a function of time for the undamped and then damped case?

I expected the undamped case to have a factor of $e^{-kt}$ where $k$ is a constant to be found. However, I haven't managed to get that, and on the computed plot I only have a periodic graph with two amplitude values with higher amplitudes for every other full period.

Note:

1. For values that are unspecified, any reasonable substitute is suffice.
2. Please specify the differential equation form used, for the undamped, and then damped case.

Comment: Do you want the steady state solution, or the "full" (time dependent) solution? The former is easy - the latter might be better done numerically.  Incidentally, "Please specify the correct differential equation form" sounds a bit like a homework assignment?

Comment: Full solution with the steady and transient. This can be done analytically. It is a problem that has bugged me for a while after attempting it several times. Without damping, I expect a exponential increase of the amplitudes as simple energy conservation, but when I try to solve the DE i.e. finding the complementary function and then a particular function, I get a periodic function with stead amplitudes over time.

Comment: One thing to consider: as you can see from your Fourier expansion, there is a DC component of force (although I think that being there for only 10% of the time, you should have a factor 0.1 in the expression). This puts the equilibrium position slightly offcenter. You might find that the equations are better behaved if you compute that offcenter position, then solve around it. Also, the solution will be an infinite series; but if you can assume that the Q factor is very high, and the force very small, the higher frequency terms can be neglected and that makes the equations simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing, I think you are making this too complicated.  The normal way to solve this problem (approximately) is to ignore all the terms in the Fourier expansion, except the one at the resonant frequency of the swing.  Then the solution is just the normal time-dependent solution for a damped oscillator forced on resonance.

Comment: Would you like to demonstrate your answer?